# Как нарисовать эллипс при помощи кубических кривых Безье

Tags: svg, графика, кривые-безье

Как нарисовать эллипс при помощи кривых Безье третьего порядка?
Одна кривая должна являться четвертью эллипса

Comment: А это возможно? Я, конечно, не специалист, но вроде как точно отрисовать дугу эллипса при помощи КБ нельзя.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov графический редактор Vectr строит эллипс четырьмя такими кривыми...это я узнал, открыв соответствующий svg файл

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что это кривые Безье, а не рациональные кривые Безье?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov кривые Б. 3 порядка

Answer (score 3):

### 1.Рисование  с помощью Дуг эллипса – Elliptical Arc (A,a)

Для этого понадобится две дуги, каждая на свою сторону.

Для половины эллипса

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="450" height="450" viewBox="0 0 450 450" >  
<path fill="skyblue" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" d="M70,200 A150 75 0 0 1 370,200 />
</svg>
```

Добавляем вторую половину эллипса в первой формуле меняем местами начало координат

1- половина -  **M70,200  A150 75 0 0 1 370,200**
2. половина - **M370,200 A150 75 0 0 1 70,200**

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="450" height="450" viewBox="0 0 450 450" >  
<path fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" d="
M70,200 A150 75 0 0 1 370,200
M 370 200 A150 75 0 0 1 70,200 "  />
</svg>
```

**Цифры после команды **A**150 75 это величины радиусов  `rx` и `ry`**

- В примере выше `rx` > `ry`  поэтому ориентация эллипса горизонтальна
- При  **`rx` < `ry`** эллипс будет вертикальный:

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M20,200 A75 150 0 0 1 170,200M 170 200 A75 150 0 0 1 20,200 "  />
</svg>
```

- **После радиусов идет атрибут угла поворота.**

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="450" height="450" viewBox="0 0 450 450" >  
<path fill="skyblue" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" d="M70,200 A150 75 45 0 1 370,200M 370 200 A150 75 45 0 1 70,200 "  />
</svg>
```

При нуле отобразится как есть, при другой величине, например 45 эллипс будет наклонен на 45 градусов

### [2. Вариант с использование онлайн генератора](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1398)

Перейдите по ссылке и получите нужную формулу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[BONUS]

*Анимация эллипсов не по теме, но вдруг пригодится кому-нибудь*

- Горизонтальная анимация rx

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  > 
 <ellipse cx="100" cy="80" rx="36" ry="50" stroke="gray" fill="purple" >
 <animate attributeName="rx" dur="4s" values="36;1;1;36;36" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
 </ellipse>
 </svg>
```

- Вертикальная анимация `ry`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" > 
 <ellipse cx="100" cy="80" rx="36" ry="50" stroke="gray" fill="purple" >
 <animate attributeName="ry" dur="4s" begin="click" values="50;0;0;50;50" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
 </ellipse>
 <text  x="75" y="85" font-size="24" fill="white" pointer-events="none" >Click </text>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Ответ хороший, но не на данный вопрос ;) Всё-таки использована path-команда A, а не С. Т.е. для эллиптической дуги в SVG есть готовый примитив, и "Безьями" рисовать не нужно.. И генератор использует базовую фигурe ellipse - кривых ведь он не выдаёт

Comment: Может, стоит исправить в первой части "кривые Безье" на дуги? ябплюсанул :)

Comment: ОК. Да и так много дуг не надо ;)

Comment: underrated answer

Answer (score 2):

Можно отрисовать эллипс с помощью четырёх кубических кривых Безье. Метод приближённый, но отклонение от истинного эллипса невелико. Именно так рисуются эллипсы в Windows GDI.

Соображения такие:
если нарисовать четверть окружности радиуса 1 в первом квадранте координатной плоскости и попытаться аппроксимировать её кривой Безье, то концевые точки `P0` и `P3` имеют координаты `(1,0)` и `(0,1)`
Касательная из точки `(1,0)` вертикальна, т.е. контрольная точка `P1` имеет координаты `(1,A)`, аналогично из симметрии `P2=(A,1)`

Кривая Безье, таким образом, описывается параметрическим уравнением

```
X(t) = 1*(1-t)^3 + 3*1*t*(1-t)^2 + 3*A*t^2*(1-t) + 0
```

и подобно для Y-составляющей.

В средней точке `t=0.5`, а X должно быть равно `sin(Pi/4)=1/Sqrt(2) ~ 0.7071`
`0.7071=0.125+0.375+0.375*A`, отсюда `A~=0.55228475`

Можно убедиться, что максимальное отклонение этой кривой от истинной дуги лежит в пределах одного пиксела на размерах порядка типичного экрана (~2000 px).

Эллипс представляет собой окружность, подвергнутую аффинному преобразованию - сжатию или растяжению вдоль осей координат, повороту вокруг центра координат (если оси эллипса не параллельны осям координат), и сдвигу. К счастью, для аффинного преобразования кривых Безье достаточно преобразовать их контрольные точки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используя данную информацию, можно написать несложную функцию для рисования произвольного эллипса - в данном случае заданного центром, полуосями, углом поворота. Реализация на Delphi, принципы должно быть нетрудно использовать в любом языке. `Pts`  - массив контрольных точек для кривых Безье, 13 точек задают 4 кривых (0,1,2,3 - первая, 3,4,5,6 - вторая и т.д.)

```
// CX, CY: кооординаты центра эллипса
// A, B : полуоси
// Angle - угол поворота в радианах
procedure EllipseAngle(Canvas: TCanvas; CX, CY, A, B: Integer; Angle: Double);
const
  DXY = 0.55228475;
var
  X, Y: array[0..12] of Single;
  DX, DY: Single;
  CF, SF: Single;
  Pts: array[0..12] of TPoint;
  i: Integer;
begin
  DX := A * DXY;
  DY := B * DXY;
  X[0] := A;    Y[0] := 0;
  X[1] := A;    Y[1] := DY;
  X[2] := DX;   Y[2] := B;
  X[3] := 0;    Y[3] := B;
  X[4] := -DX;  Y[4] := B;
  X[5] := -A;   Y[5] := DY;
  X[6] := -A;   Y[6] := 0;
  X[7] := -A;   Y[7] := -DY;
  X[8] := -DX;  Y[8] := -B;
  X[9] := 0;    Y[9] := -B;
  X[10] := DX;  Y[10] := -B;
  X[11] := A;   Y[11] := -DY;
  X[12] := A;   Y[12] := 0;
  CF := Cos(Angle);
  SF := Sin(Angle);
  for i := 0 to 12 do begin
    Pts[i].X := Round(X[i] * CF - Y[i] * SF + CX);
    Pts[i].Y := Round(X[i] * SF + Y[i] * CF + CY);
  end;
  Canvas.PolyBezier(Pts);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button23Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EllipseAngle(Canvas, 200, 200, 200, 100, - Pi/4);
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Археология это хорошо.